# Error querying the database for the first time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a curious problem. When do the first query in the database it's wrong, but on the second attempt it works perfectly, and not of the problem. What do I need to run it first?

This is the action button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(AcessoBD.ConnectionString);

    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("con", con);
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuario";

        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
           MessageBox.Show(dr["usuario"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Class `AcessoBD`:

```
public class AcessoBD
{
        static public String ConnectionString
        {
            get
            {    // pega a string de conexão do web.config
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString;
                //return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString;
            }
        }
    }
```

`App.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="Conexao"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Base\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? And you don't need to use `CommandType.Text`. It is `Text` as a defult.

Comment: @Soner Gönül when I run the first time the system, at the hour of consulting a timeout error occurs. But the second attempt he can do the query on the bench.

Comment: Seems to me that when it loads something in memory, the query is completed.

Comment: With both `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader`, you are running your query twice each time.

Comment: I removed the lines, yet the error always happens at the first appointment:
http://i.imgur.com/gSDxEi1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of this line :

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

just remove it.

`ExcuteNonQuery` used for executing queries that haven't any table result like `INSERT INTO ...`

In this line :

```
MessageBox.Show(dr["usuario"].ToString());
```

if you want to get a string from a table you should use like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(colIndex));
```

Comment: I tried doing what you told me, still did not work. At first this error always occurs:
http://i.imgur.com/gSDxEi1.png

Comment: @RonaldAraújo Can u translate it for me ?

Comment: @RonaldAraújo What suppose to get from `dr["usuario"].ToString()`?

Comment: this returns me a string, eg "Ronald"

Comment: the line is right `dr["usuario"].ToString()`. As I said earlier, the problem is only the first query. In the second query I ever get the desired value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44498/discussion-between-hamed-and-ronald-araujo)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like you run two questions.

Change this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("con", con);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
```

To:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usuario", con);
```